# HTC One and Sendgrid SMTP outgoing mail server not working

Tags: email, htc-one-x

I am using Sendgrid SMTP server for my emails on the default Mail cleint and I've set up the account on my HTC One android phone. The problem is it doesn't send emails, it keeps saying authentication failed. I've tried every combination of ports/ssl/tls and the same thing. My username/password is definitely right as I use it everywhere with no problem. I've contacted Sendgrid support but they can't figure out any problem with their servers so it may be just the way the Mail client communicates with their server. Other SMTP servers work fine on the phone, just Sendgrid doesn't.

Has anyone has problems like this with their outgoing mail servers?

Comment: Not me. But what certainly would be helpful is checking `logcat` for any error messages (either using one of the logcat apps, or via `adb logcat`) when trying to send a mail. If you have trouble interpreting the log yourself, you could upload it e.g. to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and add a link to your question.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the response. Just downloaded CatLog app and it says that I need root user to read logs otherwise it'll only show my CatLog's own log. Is this correct of all logcat apps?

Comment: Which Android version? That's true from 4.1 up (as security rules have changed). In that case, you might need to root -- or try via `adb logcat`. See [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) if you don't want to install the entire SDK for that :)